# Accessing a function from one to another dart class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I have class name LoginCard.dart in this I have another class named _FormPageState which have _validateInputs function `

```
import 'package:firstapp/Future/app_futures.dart';
import 'package:firstapp/Models/Base/EventObject.dart';
import 'package:firstapp/Widgets/SignupCard.dart';
import 'package:firstapp/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:firstapp/Components/ProgressDialog.dart';

class LoginCard extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context){
    return new Container(
      child: new LoginFormContainer(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginFormContainer extends StatefulWidget{
//  @override
 // _FormPageState createState() => _FormPageState();
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return _FormPageState();
 }
}

class _FormPageState extends State<LoginFormContainer>{

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _autoValidate = false;
 // bool _obscureText = true;

  String _email;
  String _password;

  ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog
                                  .getProgressDialog(ProgressDialogTitles.USER_LOG_IN);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(500),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black12,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 15.0),
                blurRadius: 15.0),
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black12,
                offset: Offset(0.0, -10.0),
                blurRadius: 10.0),
          ]),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0, top: 16.0),
        child: new Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidate: _autoValidate,
          child: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[loginFormUI(), progressDialog]
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget loginFormUI(){
    return new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Login",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(45),
                    fontFamily: "Poppins-Bold",
                    letterSpacing: .6)),
            SizedBox(
              height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(30),
            ),
            Text("Username",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium",
                    fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(26))),
            new TextFormField(
              autofocus: true,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              validator: validateEmail,
              onSaved: (val) =>
              _email = val,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "username",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12.0)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(30),
            ),
            Text("Password",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium",
                    fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(26))),
            new TextFormField(
              obscureText: true,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              validator: validatePassword,
              onSaved: (val) =>
              _password = val,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Password",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12.0)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(35),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Forgot Password?",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium",
                      fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(28)),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],        
    );
  }

  String validateEmail(String value){
    Pattern pattern = r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if(value.isEmpty)
      return "Email is required";
    else if(!regex.hasMatch(value))
      return 'Enter valid email';
    else
      return null;
  }

  String validatePassword(String value){
    if (value.isEmpty)
      return "Password is required";
    else
      return null;  
  }

  void _validateInputs() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      print("hello");

//    If all data are correct then save data to out variables
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      progressDialog.showProgress();
    //  _addNewUser();
      _performLogin();
    } else {
//    If all data are not valid then start auto validation.
      setState(() {
        _autoValidate = true;
      });
    }
  }

  void _performLogin() async{

    EventObject eventObject = await performLogin(_email, _password);
  }
}
```

`

and Another class name is main.dart `

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'Widgets/LoginCard.dart';
import 'Widgets/SocialIcons.dart';
import 'CustomIcons.dart';
import 'signup.dart';
//

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isSelected = false;
//  _FormPageState formPageState;
  void _radio() {
    setState(() {
      _isSelected = !_isSelected;
    });
  }

  Widget radioButton(bool isSelected) => Container(
        width: 16.0,
        height: 16.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black)),
        child: isSelected
            ? Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
              )
            : Container(),
      );

  Widget horizontalLine() => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        child: Container(
          width: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setWidth(120),
          height: 1.0,
          color: Colors.black26.withOpacity(.2),
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil.getInstance()..init(context);
    ScreenUtil.instance =
        ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
                child: Image.asset("assets/carscartoon.png"),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(),
              ),
              Image.asset("assets/image_02.png")
            ],
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0, right: 28.0, top: 60.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/tlrlogo.png",
                        width: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setWidth(110),
                        height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(110),
                      ),
                      Text("Transport Levy Record",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Poppins-Bold",
                              fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(30),
                              letterSpacing: .6,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(180),
                  ),
                  LoginCard(),
                  SizedBox(height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(40)),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 12.0,
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: _radio,
                            child: radioButton(_isSelected),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 8.0,
                          ),
                          Text("Remember me",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12, fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium"))
                        ],
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        child: Container(
                          width: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setWidth(330),
                          height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(100),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                Color(0xFF17ead9),
                                Color(0xFF6078ea)
                              ]),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Color(0xFF6078ea).withOpacity(.3),
                                    offset: Offset(0.0, 8.0),
                                    blurRadius: 8.0)
                              ]),
                          child: Material(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                              // LoginFormContainer()
                              },
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text("SIGNIN",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontFamily: "Poppins-Bold",
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                        letterSpacing: 1.0)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(40),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      horizontalLine(),
                      Text("Social Login",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0, fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium")),
                      horizontalLine()
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(40),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SocialIcons(
                        colors: [
                          Color(0xFF102397),
                          Color(0xFF187adf),
                          Color(0xFF00eaf8),
                        ],
                        iconData: CustomIcons.facebook,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      SocialIcons(
                        colors: [
                          Color(0xFFff4f38),
                          Color(0xFFff355d),
                        ],
                        iconData: CustomIcons.googlePlus,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      SocialIcons(
                        colors: [
                          Color(0xFF17ead9),
                          Color(0xFF6078ea),
                        ],
                        iconData: CustomIcons.twitter,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      SocialIcons(
                        colors: [
                          Color(0xFF00c6fb),
                          Color(0xFF005bea),
                        ],
                        iconData: CustomIcons.linkedin,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(30),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "New User? ",
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium"),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: ()  {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context, 
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
                            (context) => Signup()));
                        },
                        child: Text("SignUp",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFF5d74e3),
                                fontFamily: "Poppins-Bold")),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

On line No. 143 there is onTap function of SignIn button in my main.dart class, I want access _validateInputs() function of _FormPageState.
I am new in dart. Please let me know, if any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `_validateInputs()` function and all variables in main.dart file which is used in LoginCard.dart file and pass variables to Logincard constructor as argument from main.dart file.

In main.dart file

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

pass _formkey to LoginCard() constructor

```
LoginCard(_formKey);
```

in LoginCard.dart file

```
class LoginCard extends StatelessWidget {
 final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey;
 LoginCard(this.formKey);
 @override
 Widget build (BuildContext context){
 return new Container();
}
```